# Running a GET query using 2 indexes in Dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamodb table as follows:

```
PlaceId (String) - Partition Key
PersonName (String)
startTime (Number)
endTime (Number)
```

Now, I want to run the query which list all the names of the Person between a given range of time and with a given PlaceId.

I am thinking to make startTime and endTime as the indexes with PlaceId as the HashKey but I am not sure how can i form a query which works on 2 indexes at same time. Any idea how can I do that? Or any other better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't have indexes on start & end and use both in a single DDB query...

Best you could do, have startTime as a sortkey and then you could filter on endTime

But note that you'll still pay to read all records with a startTime in your range, filtering just throws away records before returning the data to you.

Comment: Is there no way I can form a query on 3 columns at same time. I know if instead of time, it would be some kind of value fields, I could have done concatenation, but here, I wanted to run greater than, less than queries on start and end time, so I am not sure how can I do that? Is there any way I can solve this issue in dynamodb?